# Is position fixed buggy in firefox as seen on bootstrap's official page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, browser

Recently I have been reading bootstrap from their official page and noticed a bug in firefox browser. When I visited http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ and scrolled to the very bottom then clicking on `back to top` link took the page to its top but it didn't remove the `fixed` position of the right side menu.

[image]

Is this a bug in firefox browser? Does firefox sometimes not remove position fixed? I am using Firefox 49.0.1 on windows 10.

Comment: I don't see this issue in Firefox for Mac - probabbly this could be something related to the jQuery, seems like class that has fixed property is not removed.

Comment: @Belmin I am using windows 10. The class `affix` has position relative. This class is removed on clicking on `back to top`. But the `nav` still remains fixed position with top `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both Firefox and Firefox Developer Edition (last version) to enter that page and the `fixed` position looks well for me. Maybe your browser needs an update. What version do you have? I have Firefox 49.0.2 and Firefox Developer Edition 51.0a2.

Comment: Also, try to refresh the page with Ctrl + F5, maybe is a cache problem.

Comment: Hello, I am using Firefox 49.0.1. The problem persistes on `Ctrl + F5` too.